# How to sample from Pandas DataFrame while keeping row order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given any DataFrame 2-dimensional, you can call eg. `df.sample(frac=0.3)` to retrieve a sample. But this sample will have completely shuffled row order.

Is there a simple way to get a subsample that **preserves the row order**?

Comment: I guess you can simply do: `df.head(100)` or `df.tail(100)` this would select first 100 rows from top or bottom

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer, I just want to double check what you mean by _get a subsample that preserves the row order_. Do you just want to sort the result sample, or change the way the sampling itself works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What we can do instead is use `df.sample()`, and then sort the resultant index by the original row order. Appending the `sort_index()` call does the trick. Here's my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 10))
result = df.sample(frac=0.3).sort_index()
```

You can even get it in ascending order. Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).

Comment: Thanks, somehow I couldn't find this. Yet, maybe there is another option as this seems to be adding a sorting overhead in time complexity (works for me, through).

Comment: Hmmm. If we sample randomly from the DataFrame, though, it's very hard for me to imagine mathematically enforcing this ordering constraint while preserving uniform randomness.

Comment: Shouldn't the probability of each item involved in the result be equal to the frac value? If so, you could walk through the df and compare a uniform random value with the frac value and include or exclude depending on the result. That should result in O(n) time complexity.

Comment: Oh, that sounds reasonable. I wonder how sample is implemented internally....

Answer (score 4):

The way the question is phrased, it sounds like the accepted answer does not provide a valid solution. I'm not sure what the OP really wanted; however, if we don't assume the original index is already sorted, we can't rely on `sort_index()` to reorder the rows according to their original order.

Assuming we have a DataFrame with an arbitrary index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 10), np.random.rand(100))
```

We can reset the index first to get a RangeIndex, sample, reorder, and reinstate the original index

```
df_sample = df.reset_index().sample(frac=0.3).sort_index().set_index("index")
```

And this guarantees we maintain the original order, whatever it was, whatever the index.

Finally, in case there's already a column named "index", we'll need to do something slightly different such as rename the index first, or keep it in a separate variable while we sample. But the principle remains the same.